Tic-Tac-Toe using socket.io--How manipulate enable and disable button in player's own browser
I would like to develop a tic-tac-toe game using socket.io.  Players playing the game in their own browser, i want once player1 clicks on any one button, all the button will be disabled, until player2 finish to click on the buttton in his own browser, and vice versa.  The name of my server file is index.js, while the name of my html document is index.html.
index.js:
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const http = require("http");
const {Server} = require("socket.io");
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server)
app.use(express.static(path.resolve("")))

let arr = [];
let playingArray = [];

io.on("connection", (socket)=>{

socket.on("find", (e)=>{

    if(e.name != null){

        arr.push(e.name)

        if(arr.length >=2){
            let p1obj = {
                p1name: arr[0],
                p1value: "X",
                p1move: ""      
            }
            let p2obj = {
                p2name: arr[1],
                p2value: "O",
                p2move: ""      
            }

            let obj = {
                p1: p1obj,
                p2: p2obj,
                sum:1
            }
            playingArray.push(obj);

            arr.splice(0,2);

            io.emit("find", {allPlayers: playingArray})
        
            
        }
    }

  })`

 socket.on("playing", (e)=>{
    if(e.value=="X"){
        let objToChange=playingArray.find(obj=>obj.p1.p1name===e.name);

        objToChange.p1.p1move=e.id;
        objToChange.sum++
    }
    else if(e.value=="O"){
        let objToChange=playingArray.find(obj=>obj.p2.p2name===e.name);

        objToChange.p2.p2move=e.id;
        objToChange.sum++
    }

   io.emit("playing", {allPlayers: playingArray})
   })  


   io.emit("enableButtonsClient");


   });



 app.get("/", (req,res)=>{
 return res.sendFile("index.html")
 })
 server.listen(3000,()=>{
 console.log("port connected to 3000")
 })

Below is the index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Tilt+Warp&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<style>
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 }

body {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    font-family: 'Tilt Warp', cursive;
}

h1 {
    margin: 50px 0 50px 0;
    font-size: 5rem;
    color: rgb(32, 183, 93);
    -webkit-text-stroke: .5px black;
}

input {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}

button {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

img {
    width: 30px;
}

#cont {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.btn {

    font-size: 2rem;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: rgb(206, 203, 203);
    border-radius: 10px;

}

#find {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 7px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: rgb(226, 228, 230);
}

button.enabled {
    opacity: 1;
}

p {
    font-size: 2rem;
}
</style>

<body>

<h1>Tic-Tac-Toe</h1>


<div style="display: flex; width: 95vw; position: relative;">
    <p id="userCont">You : <span id="user"></span></p>
    <p style="position: absolute; right: 0;" id="oppNameCont">Opponent : <span id="oppName"></span></p>
</div>

<br>

<p id="valueCont">You are placing as <span id="value"></span></p>

<br>

<p id="whosTurn">X's Turn</p>

<div>
    <p style="font-size: 1.2rem;" id="enterName">Enter your name : </p>

    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name" autocomplete="off">
</div>

<button id="find">Search for a player</button>
<img id="loading" src="loading.gif" alt="">

<div id="bigcont">
    <div id="cont">

        <button id="btn1" class="btn"></button>
        <button id="btn2" class="btn"></button>
        <button id="btn3" class="btn"></button>
        <button id="btn4" class="btn"></button>
        <button id="btn5" class="btn"></button>
        <button id="btn6" class="btn"></button>
        <button id="btn7" class="btn"></button>
        <button id="btn8" class="btn"></button>
        <button id="btn9" class="btn"></button>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

<script>
document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none"
document.getElementById("bigcont").style.display = "none"
document.getElementById("userCont").style.display = "none"
document.getElementById("oppNameCont").style.display = "none"
document.getElementById("valueCont").style.display = "none"
document.getElementById("whosTurn").style.display = "none"

const socket = io();

let name;

document.getElementById('find').addEventListener("click", function () {
    name = document.getElementById("name").value
    document.getElementById("user").innerText = name
    if (name == null || name == '') {
        alert("Please enter a name")
    }
   else {

        socket.emit("find", { name: name })

        document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("find").disabled = true;

    }
   })


    socket.on("find", (e) => {

    let allPlayersArray = e.allPlayers;
    console.log("html", allPlayersArray)

    if (name !=''){
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("name").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("find").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("enterName").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("bigcont").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("userCont").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("oppNameCont").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("valueCont").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("whosTurn").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("whosTurn").innerText = "X's Turn";
    }

   let oppName
   let value

   const foundObject = allPlayersArray.find(obj=>obj.p1.p1name == `${name}` || obj.p2.p2name == `${name}`);
   foundObject.p1.p1name == `${name}` ? oppName = foundObject.p2.p2name : oppName = foundObject.p1.p1name;
   foundObject.p1.p1name == `${name}` ? value = foundObject.p1.p1value : value = foundObject.p2.p2value;

   document.getElementById("oppName").innerText = oppName
   document.getElementById("value").innerText = value

})

  document.querySelectorAll(".btn").forEach(e => {
    e.addEventListener("click", function () {
        let value = document.getElementById("value").innerText
        e.innerText = value

        socket.emit("playing", { value: value, id: e.id, name: name })

    })
  })
 socket.on("playing", (e) => {
    
const foundObject = (e.allPlayers).find(obj => obj.p1.p1name == `${name}` || obj.p2.p2name == `${name}`);

    p1id = foundObject.p1.p1move
    p2id = foundObject.p2.p2move

    if ((foundObject.sum) % 2 == 0) {
        document.getElementById("whosTurn").innerText = "O's Turn"
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("whosTurn").innerText = "X's Turn"
    }



    if (p1id != '') {
        document.getElementById(`${p1id}`).innerText = "X"
        document.querySelectorAll('.btn').forEach(btn => {
                btn.disabled = true;
                btn.style.color = 'black';
            });
    }
    if (p2id != '') {
        document.getElementById(`${p2id}`).innerText = "O"
        document.querySelectorAll('.btn').forEach(btn => {
                btn.disabled = true;
                btn.style.color = 'black';
            });
    }
    })

     socket.on("enableButtonsClient", () => {
     document.querySelectorAll(".btn").forEach((btn) => {
     if (btn.innerText !== "X" && btn.innerText !== "O") {
     btn.disabled = false;
     btn.style.color = "initial";
   }
   });
   });
  </script>
  </html>

    
     I expect the buttons without "X" or "O" are enabled again in player2's browser, but all the buttons are kept disable, what's wrong? 


I find your issue is with this code
socket.on("enableButtonsClient", () => {
 document.querySelectorAll(".btn").forEach((btn) => {
 if (btn.innerText !== "X" && btn.innerText !== "O") {
 btn.disabled = false;
 btn.style.color = "initial";}}}

Your issue is that you are using innerText. innerText returns HTML code, and therefore it will not work effectively. Using textContent may help out
    socket.on("enableButtonsClient", () => {
  document.querySelectorAll(".btn").forEach((btn) => {
     if (btn.textContent !== "X" && btn.textContent !== "O") {
     btn.disabled = false;
     btn.style.color = "initial";
   }
   })}


Let me know if this helps
